# How to add extension method to a subcomponent in a framework

Tags: ios, swift, extension-methods, foxit

Using Foxit, a PDF rendering engine. Its public view component is `FSPDFViewCtrl`. `FSPDFViewCtrl` is able to import. But unfortunately I need to add an extension method into one of the subcomponent in `FSPDFViewCtrl` called `DvPageScrollView`. But I am not able to do that. What to do? Any way to add extension method to it?

`shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith` method need to propagte gestures to the behind tableview.

[image]

Comment: First of all make sure you import the framework, and second of all if its marked as file private or private there is no way to do it.

Comment: Post code as text not as an image.